# How to calibrate screen colour in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: color-management, icc

The color on the screen of my Dell XPS 15 is rather blue-ish. The D55 (5500K) profile is too yellow and D60 is too cold.

Ideally I'd like a profile configured at 5700k, or somewhere in that zone. None of the other profiles suit my needs.

**UPDATE:**
While I have yet to find a proper solution, I managed to tweak the color of my screen with redshift. Not an ideal solution, but it does the trick for the time being.

**UPDATE 2:**
This can be done with the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-temperature <temperature>
```

Comment: In the meantime I bought a dell XPS 13 9370 and its default white point is much better than the previous XPS 15.

Answer (score 6):

You can import color profile in **Settings** -> **Devices** -> **Color** (only for X.org sessions).

[image: Screenshot]

Select your display and click on *Import profile* button

You can install default color profiles using `sudo apt install icc-profiles` or find your profile [here](http://www.tftcentral.co.uk/articles/icc_profiles.htm)

Also you can calibrate your screen manually in settings (unfortunately, that button is disabled in my system and I don't know why) or using `gcm-calibrate`:

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-settings-daemon

$ colormgr get-devices # take note of the Device ID of the one with Type: display, e.g. "xrandr-Acme Corp"

$ gcm-calibrate --device="some Device ID"
```

This method requires an external display calibration hardware. The simplest way is to calibrate your screen in Windows and them export profile and apply it in your Linux system.

For more info, I recommend to take a look at [this article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ICC_profiles) at Arch Wiki

Also, AFAIK display calibration might not available in Wayland session for now.

Comment: Thanks, but the button is disabled for me too. I think it has to do with the requirement of a calibration device. In the meantime I bought a new laptop and the default screen colour is much better, so the issue resolved itself that way.

Comment: After installing gnome-color-manager, `gcm-import --help` works, but `gcm-calibrate: command not found`. Also, there is this scary commit: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-color-manager/-/commit/5a1bf35e30ff689c727222fae1f31b0d4be4ae9d It says "Remove the calibration tools | This is not maintained, and does not work well." Authored on March 3, 2020. What does this mean for us?

Comment: Installing the package `gnome-color-manager` seems to enable the `View Details` button. In my case the dialog says then `Display Correction: No`. I guess, it is not available then.